# simple sidebar menu transition probs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a simple sidebar menu that I would like to apply two way transition but only one direction is working.

HTML:

```
<div class="content"><button id="menu-open">open</button></div>
<nav class="menu">....</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:-300px;
  top:0;
}

.menu-open{
-webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#menu-open').click(function(){
$('.menu').toggleClass('menu-open');
$('.content').toggleClass('menu-open');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give transition to `.content` and `.menu` class will give you reverse transition.

Because toggleClass will remove `menu-open` class from both so, transition effect will not work.

```
.menu{
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:-300px;
  top:0;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
   transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  }

.content{
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
   -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease;
   -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
   transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  }
```

And Remove transition from `.menu-open`.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0owunhg/1/)**